# Q: Google Sheet Script to alter columns so in front of numbers its adding an hashtag

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

im looking for help/script where it replace/append a number (1-999) within several colums (example: A10:D200) with an additional hashtag (#1 - #999).

**Example Before:**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 31 | 5 |
| 6 | 888 | 123 | 9 |
| 92 | 55 | 3 | 791 |
| 11 | 2 | 456 | 712 |

**How it should look:**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #123 | #456 | #31 | #5 |
| #6 | #888 | #123 | #9 |
| #92 | #55 | #3 | #791 |
| #11 | #2 | #456 | #712 |

and so on

```
function onEdit() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Stewarding - Imola Q")
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()
      var range = sheet.getRange(10, 1, lastRow, 4)
      var to_replace = [0-9];
      var replace_with = "#";
      var data  = range.getValues();
    
        var oldValue="";
        var newValue="";
        var cellsChanged = 0;
    
        for (var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
          for (var i=0; i<data[r].length; i++) {
            oldValue = data[r][i];
            newValue = data[r][i].replace(to_replace, replace_with +oldValue);
            if (oldValue!=newValue)
            {
              cellsChanged++;
              data[r][i] = newValue;
            }
          }
        }
        range.setValues(data);
        //Logger.log(data);
    }
```

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You should add more information relating to what you have tried, what is going wrong and what you would like to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively it can be done this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // your sheet
  const range = sheet.getRange('A10:D200'); // your range

  // find all digits and put # before
  range.createTextFinder('(\\d+)').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('#$1');
}
```

To prevent double `##` after a rerun of the scipt the last line could be like this:

```
range.createTextFinder('^\\D*(\\d+)').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('#$1');
```

It will change any number of any non-digits characters before digits with one `#` at the start of every cell of the range.

Comment: yeah thats helps alot, but if i now edit on column B (for an example) it will add an additional # infront every other number.

If i take one row for an example and type it from A to D, i got 4x # infront of A | 3 infront of B | 2 infront of C

Comment: You can add one more line: `range.createTextFinder('^##+').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('#');` It will replace two or more of `#` at the start of cell with one `#`.

Comment: Or you can use this line: `range.createTextFinder('^\\D*(\\d+)').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('#$1');` It will replace `any non digits + digits` with `# + digits`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `newValue = '#' + String(data[r][i]);` work?

if you have some conditions where you don't want a `'#'` just add an if statement